# How do I use group_by and case_when to impute a new value in a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to wrap my head around this data wrangling problem. My conjoint study output df looks similar to this:

```
   id set_number card_number att1 att2 att3 att4 score
1 932          1           1    1    1    1    3     0
2 932          1           2    2    2    4    4   100
3 932          1           3    8    8    8    8     0
4 932          2           1    3    3    3    1     0
5 932          2           2    4    2    2    4     0
6 932          2           3    8    8    8    8   100
7 933          1           1    1    1    1    3     0
8 933          1           2    2    2    4    4   100
9 933          1           3    8    8    8    8     0
...
```

Where `id` refers to a person and `score` is a dependent variable. I need to reformat the df in order to run an analysis using [ChoiceModelR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ChoiceModelR/ChoiceModelR.pdf) package.

I am trying to figure out how to write a code (I am guessing using group_by(id and card_number) and case_when/if else statements) that would impute the card_number in the top row corresponding to each set_number, if a score is 100 for that card number. However, the score needs to be "card_number + 1" if all att1 to att4 are 8s.

The desired df needs to look like so:

```
   id set_number card_number att1 att2 att3 att4 score
1 932          1           1    1    1    1    3     2
2 932          1           2    2    2    4    4     0
3 932          1           3    8    8    8    8     0
4 932          2           1    3    3    3    1     4
5 932          2           2    4    2    2    4     0
6 932          2           3    8    8    8    8     0
7 933          2           1    3    3    3    1     2
8 933          2           2    4    2    2    4     0
9 933          2           3    8    8    8    8     0

...
```

I would really appreciate any help.

My complete dataset in csv. format is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jP0_GI72CTVHAiNTBUEnp8yZo2ijor8K/view?usp=sharing)

Dput output

```
structure(list(id = c(932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 932L, 
932L, 932L, 932L), set_number = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L), card_number = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L), att1 = c(1L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 3L), att2 = c(1L, 
2L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 1L), att3 = c(1L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 8L, 2L), att4 = c(3L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 
2L, 8L, 2L), score = c(0L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 0L, 0L, 100L, 
0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: I think I could help but I dont get the calculation. Why is score 2 and 4 in the two examples?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The score is 2 because a person picked card_number 2 (Assigned value 100 to it and 0s to cards number 1 and 3, as in the first table). The score needs to be 4 if a person picks card number 3 AND all attributes are 8s.

Comment: I really don't know anything about `ChoiceModelR` but would look closely at the format. If you can have duplicate `id` and `set_number` combinations, then you may need to do something else for grouping and this may be more complicated. I wish I could be of more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not the most efficient way of solving this, but here it goes (I would also welcome any other way of achieving the same thing):

```
df$dv = 0

for (i in seq(1, nrow(df),by = 3)){
  if(df$score[i] == 100)
  {df$dv[i] = 1}
  if(df$score[i+1] == 100)
  {df$dv[i] = 2}
  if(df$score[i+2] == 100)
  {df$dv[i] = 4}
}
```

`dv` is a new column that stores updated scores. I then just removed `score` column with a subset function.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based in the tidyverse can look as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

as_tibble(df) %>%
  group_by(id, set_number) %>%
  mutate(scoreX = card_number[which(score == 100)][1],
         scoreX = pmap_dbl(list(att1, att2, att3, att4, score, scoreX),
                           ~ if_else(sum(..1, ..2, ..3, ..4) == 32 & ..5 == 100, 
                                     ..6 + 1, as.double(..6))),
         scoreX = max(scoreX),
         scoreX = if_else(row_number() == min(row.names(.)), scoreX, 0))


#       id set_number card_number  att1  att2  att3  att4 score scoreX
#    <int>      <int>       <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <dbl>
#  1   932          1           1     1     1     1     3     0      2
#  2   932          1           2     2     2     4     4   100      0
#  3   932          1           3     8     8     8     8     0      0
#  4   932          2           1     3     3     3     1     0      2
#  5   932          2           2     4     2     2     4   100      0
#  6   932          2           3     8     8     8     8     0      0
#  7   932          3           1     5     4     1     3     0      2
#  8   932          3           2     6     3     3     2   100      0
#  9   932          3           3     8     8     8     8     0      0
# 10   932          4           1     3     1     2     2     0     NA
```

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. Here is my complete [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jP0_GI72CTVHAiNTBUEnp8yZo2ijor8K/view?usp=sharing) in csv format. I've tried running your code, but getting the following error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `scoreX`.
x `false` must be a double vector, not an integer vector.
i Input `scoreX` is `pmap_dbl(...)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: id = 103, set_number = 1.

Comment: I am guessing that's because the columns in your example are <dbl> rather than integer? I tried pmap_int, but getting the same error as above.

Comment: @RakhimRakhimov: My pleasure. Can you please put some of your data into ```dput()``` and post the output?

Comment: @RakhimRakhimov: Using ```dput()``` and posting the result on the site is the easiest way of ensuring that we are working on the same data. The problem seemingly has to do with outputting scoreX from ```if_else()``` inside ```pmap_dbl()```. But let's see when we know we are processing the same data.

Comment: Hey, [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10rb3fIgBso31sh12MB0EVbQPKXjIcaL7/view?usp=sharing) is a dput output saved in txt format (the dataset is too long to post here).

Comment: @RakhimRakhimov: Thank you. I'm not trying to be a pain, but I need you to pass on the output from ```dput()``` in your post. I won't need all of the data. The first ten rows should do nicely (especially considering the fact that we seem to be dealing inconsistency in types). So something like ```dput(slice(df, 1:10))``` would be great.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224155/discussion-between-rakhim-rakhimov-and-rjen).